# Macvim Nerdtree File Path Issue

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

I am using `Macvim` some how about a year ago I got Nerdtree working for file browsing.

When I save a file I get a error that says,

```
Error detected while processing function checksyntax#Check:

E344 Can't find directory "/Users/MyMac/NERD_tree_1" in cdpath
E472 Command failed
```

Then I go in to finder and check and the new file is there.

But it is not updated in my Nerdtree till I open a new instance of macvim.

Any Ideas how I can fix this? Or where to look?

I obviously need to update this file path,

Where can this be done at?

Comment: This seems to be an error with either [NerdTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) or [checksyntax_vim](https://github.com/tomtom/checksyntax_vim). Please make sure you have the latest versions and submit an issue to one of these projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, His answer gave me light on refreshing but updating all my plugins was the trick. It has been so long since I used vim but thanks to you I have it all working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press `r` to refresh the current directory's listing or `R` to refresh the root directory's listing

Comment: Awesome thanks that makes sense. But what about updating the path which is the main issue here? It is saving the file but telling me the path to the dir of nerdTree is wrong.